# What exactly does "use msbuild to obtain project references" do?

Tags: visual-studio-2012

In vs2012, project (.csproj, at any rate) properties have the option "use msbuild to obtain project references", does anybody know what exactly does it do? Doesn't vs2012 use MsBuild internally anyways?

Comment: Very obscure, only two google hits and this is one of them.  Looks like its specific to web projects and should only be used if they generate an assembly dynamically.  Sounds like trouble.

Comment: Are you sure this isn't a resharper option?

Comment: It could have been... no way to know now.